System.Collection.Hashtable does not contain a method named 'Trim'
below code throws runtime exception System.Collection.Hashtable does not contain a method named 'Trim' what's the best solution below script? I just wanted to extract username. IP addtess, Computer-Name, pages printed, and export it to csv file.
$logPath = "Micros<sub>your text</sub>oft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"
$eventId = 307
$ipAddress = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias (Get-NetConnectionProfile).InterfaceAlias).IPAddress
if (-not $ipAddress) {
    $ipAddress = "NoIPAddress"
}
$todayDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$csvFilePath = "C:\test\$ipAddress-$todayDate.csv"
$filteredEvents = Get-WinEvent -LogName $logPath -FilterXPath "*[System[(EventID=$eventId) and (TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000])]]"

if ($filteredEvents.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No events found with Event ID $eventId in log $logPath for today or yesterday."
} else {
    $eventsToExport = @() # Initialize the array
    foreach ($event in $filteredEvents) {
        $eventDate = $event.TimeCreated.Date
        if ($eventDate -eq (Get-Date).Date -or $eventDate -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date) {
            $messageParts = $event.Message -split "`r`n"
            $user = $printer = $pagesPrinted = $timeCreated = $hostName = $port = $null
            foreach ($line in $messageParts) {
                if ($line -match "owned by\s+(.+?)\s+on\s+(.+?)\s+was printed on\s+(.+?)\s+through port\s+(.+?)\.\s+Size in bytes: .+ Pages printed: (\d+)\.") {
                    $user = $Matches.Trim()
                    $hostName = $Matches.Trim()
                    $printer = $Matches.Trim()
                    $port = $Matches.Trim()
                    $pagesPrinted = $Matches.Trim()
                    Write-Host "Matched User: $user, HostName: $hostName, Printer: $printer, Port: $port, Pages Printed: $pagesPrinted"
                } else {
                    Write-Host "No matches found for line: $line"
                }
            }
            $eventsToExport += [PSCustomObject]@{
                User = $user
                Printer = $printer
                PagesPrinted = $pagesPrinted
                TimeCreated = $event.TimeCreated.ToString("M/d/yyyy H:mm")
                HostName = $hostName
                Port = $port
                IP = $ipAddress
            }
        }
    }
    if ($eventsToExport.Count -gt 0) {
        $eventsToExport | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
        Write-Host "Filtered events with Event ID $eventId for today or yesterday saved to $csvFilePath"
    } else {
        Write-Host "No events found for today or yesterday."
    }
}


The automatic $Matches variable is a hashtable of matched values. Use indexes to access elements. Index 0 contains entire match and other matches are from left to right. Update your code with something like this:
$user = $Matches[1].Trim()
$hostName = $Matches[2].Trim()
$printer = $Matches[3].Trim()
$port = $Matches[4].Trim()
$pagesPrinted = $Matches[5].Trim()

See this for more info about regular expressions in Powershell.

Good info; there are two things worth noting: in order for other, substring matches to be recorded, they must be inside capture groups ((...)). While these are indeed accessible via indices starting with 1 by default, named capture groups must be accessed by their name; e.g.: $null = 'foo' -match 'f(?<o_chars>o+)'; $Matches['o_chars']
